# How do I equally space navbar elements using Bulma?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm wondering if there's a way to equally space elements in Bulma's navbar; I've looked into the documentation, and was unable to find anything that does that. I also tried stuff like:

```css
.x{
  text-align: justify;
}

.x:after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

but the elements are still all on one side.

How should I go about evenly spacing these navbar elements?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Bulma can do this natively, but some custom CSS can get the job done. I added a new class called `navbar-center`.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-center">
    <div class="navbar-item"><a href="">Link #1</a></div>
    <div class="navbar-item"><a href="">Link #2</a></div>
    <div class="navbar-item"><a href="">Link #3</a></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-center {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is-fullwidth` class, works for horizontal tab elements in nav:

```
<nav class="tabs is-fullwidth">
    <ul>
      <li class="is-active"><a>Overview</a></li>
      <li><a>Modifiers</a></li>
      <li><a>Grid</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Docs: https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/hero/#fullheight-with-navbar